# Android view support margin?

Tags: android, view, margin

From the developer guide it says that

> though a view can define a padding, it does not provide any support for margins. However, view groups provide such a support.

but why i can set `layout_margin` attributes in `ImageView`,`EditView` and so on,they exist and work just like padding,

I can't understand what the guide says, Can someone help me to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically that means that margins are defined in xml for child views, but are used by their parent.

Technically, paddings are fields of the View class. Paddings are being used in the View.draw() method by a View itself. See:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/view/View.java#15156

Margins are fields of the MarginLayoutParams class. Margins are used by a ViewGroup to layout its children. See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

EDIT:

Margins are loaded to MarginLayoutParams and then used in the layouting phase.

Method which uses these xml attributes to create MarginLayoutParams in FrameLayout:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/FrameLayout.java#678

Loading margins: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#6619

Layouting: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#1539

Comment: from the first link i see that when view is drawing,only paddings make sense,but i think it is for the content which we can see, i don't understand how the margin works,and more important is the existence of margin, i can't find margin attribute in guide,but they can be applied to view, i am confused about this

Comment: so the view doesn't have margin is right,though edittext extends view but it gets the margin params from its layout,and when drawing itself margin is not used,but when in layout,the container uses margin to decide how to position the child view,right?

Answer (score 0):

View class does not contain margins. It contains the padding because padding offset the contents of the view. Margin is meant to offset the view itself from the parent, ViewGroup. As such, the margins are contained in the ViewGroup class.
However remember the principle of inheritance. A view is a child of the ViewGroup class. As a result, it inherits the properties of the ViewGroup, including the margins. So when you apply the margin on the view, it responds because it already has the margins properties by virtue of inheritance.